# Time of waiting to exit out from the question ban

Tags: support, questions, user-accounts, post-ban

Having since a few days this message *"You have reached your question limit. Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."*

I wanted to know the time duration of my blocked account as I am currently unable to ask a question. I have tried in every way to improve my questions.

Comment: What did you find when you clicked on the link shown to you as part of that message?

Comment: @DavidZ In particular clicking on the link I read this: "Begin by improving your existing questions: do as much as possible to make them clear, specific and on-topic. The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh the cost of those questions which were poorly received. Edit all of your questions, paying special attention to those that score 0 or less.". I do not know what can be improved since some of them are voted positive and the same negative.

Comment: What about the rest of the page?

Comment: @DavidZ "Does the ban last forever?
If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one **6 months** after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated. If you see a similar message when trying to post an answer, please see our guidance on what to do about answer bans." So I have to wait until next year?

Comment: The exact dates are not public. On different rumors, as far I know, you will be back between 2 weeks and a half year. It depends on, how deep is your question record. If it is your first time, probably you survived with 2 weeks. What the system counts: 1) count of your questions with negative score 2) count of your closed questions 3) count of your deleted questions (even if you own-deleted them!). So, fix what you can and hope. There is another rumor, maybe even if you can get some ups to your questions, you will be allowed to get back.

Comment: @peterh The dates are, in fact, public -- [if banned, one can ask a single new question after 6 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/174806). And if one can contribute meaningfully in other ways, and/or improve their existing posts, the ban can be lifted earlier than that. In theory, the ban is forever unless one does something to improve their content on the site. Practically, every 6 months one can try to ask a new question and if it goes well, that can lift the ban.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97601/discussion-on-question-by-sebastiano-time-of-waiting-to-exit-out-from-the-questi).

Comment: I've transferred some comments to a chat room as mentioned in the above autogenerated comment.

Comment: @DavidZ Thank you very much.